# How to add extra JSON in existing local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I collected the data like `name, mobile number, email address` from registration page and stored in a local storage in the key name '`user_details`'.

Now the details are shown in profile page, additionally I want to collect the data like `age and gender` and I want to store in the same local storage in the same JSON '`user_details`'.

I don't know how to do like that.

example:

```
user_detail = [
   {
      Name:"string",
      Mobile_number:"1234567890",
      email_address:"abcd@gmail.com",
   }
]
```

Every object is the detail of a single user. I want to save `age and gender` at the object of a particular user.(`user_detail` is an array of `multiple user`).

I tried to store the newly collecting data in the same json which exist in local storage.

I want the `user_detail` key to save the data which I collected from registration page as well as from profile page.

Comment: You need to read the existing data and decode it. Then you need to find the relevant object to update in your array - and update it. And afterwards, you encode the whole thing as JSON again, and write it back to the storage ...

Answer (score 2):

You can update the existing JSON object in the local storage with the new data by following these steps:

1. Retrieve the existing user details JSON object from the local
   storage using the getItem method of the localStorage object.

```
let userDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_details'));
```

2. Add the new properties for age and gender to the user details object
   for the current user.

```
userDetails[currentUserIndex].age = ageValue;
userDetails[currentUserIndex].gender = genderValue;
```

Here, currentUserIndex is the index of the current user in the userDetails array, and ageValue and genderValue are the new age and gender values that you want to add to the object.

3. Store the updated user details object back into the local storage
   using the setItem method of the localStorage object.

```
localStorage.setItem('user_details', JSON.stringify(userDetails));
```

This will overwrite the existing user_details key with the updated JSON object that includes the new age and gender data for the current user.